# Error while trying to use .startsWith() and .contains() methods in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, methods

When I try to use the methods .startsWith and .contains with the variable value, I get the words in red, because apparently, they do not exist.

Can someone help with this error? I tried looking on the internet to see if this is an old deprecated function but I did not find anything apparently it is not deprecated...
[Click to see the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFYGG.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated my old Android studio from 4.1.2 to the new ARTIC FOX 2020.3.1... and the error magically disappeared...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are leaving an space after calling the contains function. So is like you are not sending any arguments to the function.
It should be like this:

```
value.contains("/")
```

And same for startsWith

```
value.startsWith("-")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still does not work. I still get the error if I leave no spaces as you proposed.